# How to Convert Month Name to Month Number in java Using JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Hello Guys i want to convert Month name to Month number, i am using a code form but it looks like childish.

i have 12 month in JCombobox

```
        JCombobox month_sands = new JComboBox();

        month_sands.addItem("January");
        month_sands.addItem("February");
        month_sands.addItem("March");
        month_sands.addItem("April");
        month_sands.addItem("May");
        month_sands.addItem("June");
        month_sands.addItem("July");
        month_sands.addItem("August");
        month_sands.addItem("September");
        month_sands.addItem("October");
        month_sands.addItem("November");
        month_sands.addItem("December");
```

So here i want to get the month number when i select the month

Example i have written a code to convert the month to number,

```
String month=null;
 if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("January"))
    {
        month="01";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("February"))
    {
        month="02";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("March"))
    {
        month="03";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("April"))
    {
        month="04";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("May"))
    {
        month="05";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("June"))
    {
        month="06";
    }   
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("July"))
    {
        month="07";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("August"))
    {
        month="08";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("September"))
    {
        month="09";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("October"))
    {
        month="10";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("November"))
    {
        month="11";
    }
    if(month_sands.getSelectedItem().equals("December"))
    {
        month="12";
    }
```

but am not Happy with this code, is there any other way to make it short form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getSelectedIndex()` instead of `getSelectedItem()` and add `1` to it to get month number.

Comment: Yes: much better

Answer (score 0):

i suggest use this code:

read more about `JCombobox` and `getSelectedIndex` method

```
String month = null;

if(month_sands.getSelectedIndex() != -1){
     month_sands = "0"+(month_sands.getSelectedIndex() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this for every object, that is shown in JComboBox:
Create a custom object for the comboboxes like this

```
IdAndName idAndName= new IdAndName(month, id);
```

Then you add all you values to it at set the list of IdAndNames as model of the combobox.

```
combobox.setModel(list);
```

Once you have done that, you can display the 'name' and if you want to get the id, you can get it like this:

```
combobox.getSelectedItem().getId;
```

I use this template for all comboboxes